# ORA-01427 while UPDATE self-join ORACLE

Tags: oracle

two tables, each has employee_id and manager_id which links to employee_id Tables have different employee_id.

```
UPDATE employee u
SET u.manager_id = (SELECT m.id
    FROM employee e
    JOIN old_db.employees oe ON e.last_name = oe.last_name
    JOIN old_db.employees om ON oe.manager_id = om.employee_id
    INNER JOIN employee m ON m.last_name = om.last_name
    WHERE e.id = u.id)
WHERE manager_id IS NULL;
```

gives

`ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

I've tried `rownum=1` but this makes all `manager_id` same.

Select query with one given `employee_id` returns one value

```
SQL> SELECT m.id
  2     FROM employee e
  3     JOIN old_db.employees oe ON e.last_name = oe.last_name
  4     JOIN old_db.employees om ON oe.manager_id = om.employee_id
  5     INNER JOIN employee m ON m.last_name = om.last_name
  6     WHERE e.id = 1805;

        ID
----------
      1804
```

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: Looks like you know the problem. The query gives more than one result for one or more employees. You should review the logic behind that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the root cause of problem is in table `employees` or in table `employee` `last_name` are not unique. And when you join table on last name you get more then one row. You may check it with next query:

```
SELECT e.id, count(*), count(distinct m.id)
FROM employee e
JOIN old_db.employees oe ON e.last_name = oe.last_name
JOIN old_db.employees om ON oe.manager_id = om.employee_id
INNER JOIN employee m ON m.last_name = om.last_name
GROUP BY e.id;
```

May be exists more suitable column to join it for example `employee_id` if so you query may be rewritten to:

```
UPDATE employee u
SET u.manager_id = (SELECT oe.manager_id 
                    FROM old_db.employees oe
                   WHERE oe.employee_id = u.id)
WHERE manager_id IS NULL;
```